# Firebase swift runTransactionBlock : Cast from 'MutableData?' to unrelated type 'String' always fails

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, nsmutabledata

I need to run transactionBlock over a value, instead of a child.

Data structure:

```
-parent
    - child : value
```

When I try to cast the MutableData I'll get from child I have a crash. Xcode throws the warning confirming that:

```
 Cast from 'MutableData?' to unrelated type 'String' always fails
```

Snip of the code

```
Database.database().reference().child("parent").child("child").runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: MutableData!) -> TransactionResult in
                                        
    /**
     *
     * When runTransaction is called, it called straight away doTransaction with a supposed currentData that is the cached value and is often nil the first call.
     * Inside the doTransaction I have to make some actions based to the supposed actual data. Those actions have to work on the new value I want to set for the
     * currentData. Once that is done i send currentData gathered from currentDta.getDtata() which on the first call is just supposed and often nil and the
     * new value that i set with currentData.setData(). If the supposed current value and real current value are the same then I wite the data with the value set
     * in setData() , otherwise I do nothing and I go back with the real value I have in the database in that moment and I repeat.
     *
     *
     */
    
 
    let currentDataValue = currentData.value as! String
```

Below a screenshot as requested:
[image]

From official Documentation this should be doable : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRMutableData

How is the correct way to do that? All the examples found are with child [String:Any]
I can't snapshot millions of records from parent just to check/write one child.

Thank you.

Comment: [`MutableData.value`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRMutableData#value) can return multiple types, but not a `MutableData?`. Are you sure the error message comes from the code you shared?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen added the screenshot requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who came across the same, see below

[image]